# dropdown list with an extend option

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm using the DropdownList component from [react-widget](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/dropdownlist?_k=4okhy4). In my code, there are a couple of dropdowns that get their values from an Ajax call. Some of them, like a list of languages, are too big and it's very slow to get the list from Ajax and render it (takes 4 to 5 seconds!). I would like to provide to the dropdwon a small list of languages and an 'Extend' or 'Load Full List' option; if clicking on Extend the dropdown would be refreshed with the full list of languages. 
Here is my solution: the code of the parent component:

```
const languages = ajaxCalls.getLanguages();
const langs = {"languages": [["eng", "English"], ["swe", "Swedish"], ["deu", "German"], ["...", "Load Full List"]]};
const common_langs = langs.languages.map(([id, name]) => ({id, name}));

<SelectBig data={common_langs} extend={languages} onSelect={x=>this.setValue(schema, path, x)} value={this.getValue(path)} />;
```

And here is the code for `SelectBig` component:

```
import React from 'react/lib/ReactWithAddons';
import { DropdownList } from 'react-widgets';

const PT = React.PropTypes;

export const SelectBig = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        data: PT.array,
        value: PT.string,
        onSelect: PT.func.isRequired,
    },

    maxResults: 50,

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log("nextProps = " , nextProps, " , nextState = ",  nextState);
        const len = x => (x && x.length !== undefined) ? x.length : 0;
        // fast check, not exact, but should work for our use case
        return nextProps.value !== this.props.value
            || len(nextProps.data) !== len(this.props.data);
    },

    getInitialState(){
        return {
            lastSearch: '',
            results: 0,
            dataList: [],
        };
    },

    select(val) {
        if(val.id === "..."){
            this.setState({dataList: this.props.extend})
        }
        this.props.onSelect(val.id);
    },

    filter(item, search) { .... },

    renderField(item) {  ....  },

    render() {
        const busy = !this.props.data;
        let data;
        if(!this.props.extend){
            data = this.props.data || [];
        } else {
            data = this.state.dataList;    
        }

        return (
            <DropdownList
                data={data}
                valueField='id'
                textField={this.renderField}
                value={this.props.value}
                onChange={this.select}
                filter={this.filter}
                caseSensitive={false}
                minLength={2}
                busy={busy} />
        );
    }
});
```

But it doesn't look good: When the user chooses 'Load Full List', the dropdown list will be closed and user need to click again to see the updated list. Does anyone have a better solution or a suggestion to improve my code?

The picture shows how it looks like right now!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-2 
Better go with this link, it will work